# How to create django project

Tags: python, django, cmd

I’m not sure what commands should I write in CMD to create a Python django project. When I write `django-admin startproject myproject`, it does not create a config folder in my project. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using "$ django-admin startproject myproject",  the myproject should be the folder that contains your project.

If that doesn't work try checking this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_creating_project.htm
And follow the steps.

Comment: Wherever possible, please recommend [official tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) instead of random third-party tutorials. Official ones are nearly always better.